# If I wanted to buy a card protector for every card in Arkham Horror (and expansions), how many would I need of each type?

Tags: arkham-horror, game-accessories

I've been considering purchasing a whack of [Fantasy Flight Supply board game sleeves](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite.asp?eidm=86&enmi=Fantasy%20Flight%20Supply) for my Arkham Horror game and expansions.  Does anyone know how many of each type of sleeve I would need to purchase to cover the various cards in the main box and all of the expansions to date?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need:

```
Set                     Investigator   Ancient One
Arkham Horror              189             179
Curse of the Dark Pharoah   76              90
Dunwich Horror             152             180
The King in Yellow          76              90
Kingsport Horror           112             207
Black Goat of the Woods     90              88
Innsmouth Horror            96             176
Lurker at the Threshold     56             110
Miskatonic Horror          112             336

Total                      959            1456
```

According to the [Fantasy Flight Sleeve Guide](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/ffg-supply/PDF/supply-list-brochure-web.pdf), that equates to 20 packs of Mini American Board Game Sleeves and 30 packs of Standard American Board Game Sleeves if you have everything.

Answer (score 0):

Answer updated for Miskatonic Horror and Revised Curse of the Dark Pharaoh. Based on Pat Ludwig's answer. You will need:

```
Set                                   Investigator   Ancient One
Arkham Horror                             189             179
Curse of the Dark Pharaoh (revised)        76              90
Dunwich Horror                            152             180
The King in Yellow                         76              90
Kingsport Horror                          112             207
Black Goat of the Woods                    90              88
Innsmouth Horror                           96             176
Lurker at the Threshold                    56             110
Miskatonic Horror                         112             336

Total                                     959            1456
```

According to the Fantasy Flight Sleeve Guide, that equates to 20 packs of Mini American Board Game Sleeves and 30 packs of Standard American Board Game Sleeves if you have everything. Fantasy Flight lists the Mini Americans at $2.49, and the Standard American at $2.99, so the total cost would be about $139.50 + tax.

Comment: in general you should favor editing an answer to update it instead of posting a new one.  Also, accepting your answer to your question doesn't award rep or guarantee that it will be the first answer.  (It would be, if it had the highest votes.

Comment: @Pat Ludwig - I should have just responded to you with the updates, my apologies!